# Building the .apk file from python file on android

Tags: android, python

My project is to make a simple python application that runs on Android device . In this step , i have a python file in :"Memoire du telephone/sl4a/scripts" , and want to create the APK file to can run it on other device . I am using SL4A and Python3 for Android . Thank you .

Comment: I think **SL4A and Python3 for Android must be packed on your apk** or **SL4A and Python3 for Android must be installed on target device** (The packed apks will install on the installation of your main apk. Then _you can invoke SL4A by setting Python3 for Android along with your desired script on your application startup_ . Alternatively you can clone SL4A & Python3 for Android, and compile into single application along with your desired scripts.

Comment: Can you clarify your question. **Are trying to run a python file in :"Memoire du telephone/sl4a/scripts" folder in your phone?** OR **Are you trying to build an APK, which installs the python file on another phone with necessary dependencies and able to run on that phone?**

Comment: Yes , the second one , the python file is running right now on the android device using :"sl4a" and "python3 for android" . I don't know the steps to follow to build the .APK file , to can install it in other android device . Thank you .